# When I prove two topologies are same, is it sufficient to prove they have same basis? If so,Why?

Tags: general-topology

> $(X, \mathcal{T}_X), (Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological space, and let
>   $A, B$ be subset of $X,Y$ respectively.
>
> Now, $(X \times Y, \mathcal{T}_{X \times Y})$ be product topology. $A
>  \times B \subset X \times Y$. Consider subspace topology
>   $\mathcal{T}_1$ on $A \times B$
>
> Also, $(A, \mathcal{T}_A), (B, \mathcal{T}_B)$ where $\mathcal{T}_A$
>   and $\mathcal{T}_B$ are subspace topologies on $A, B$
>   respectively,consider product topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ on $A \times B$
>
> Prove $\mathcal{T}_1 = \mathcal{T}_2$

My idea is to show that the bases of $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ are same.
where $\mathcal{T}_1$ basis is {$(A \times B) \cap (U \times V)  | (U \times V) \in \mathcal{T}_{X \times Y}$}

and $\mathcal{T}_2$ basis is {$U_0 \times V_0 | U_0 \in \mathcal{T}_A,  V_0 \in \mathcal{T}_B$}. I know how to show these two bases are equal. However, I don't if this is sufficient to prove two topologies are equal.

Comment: In general yes. But for this question it isn't really necessary.

Comment: That should work. A basis generates a topology. If that is not convincing enough you could suppose one topology has an element that the other does not have. You should be able to dismiss that case with a simple contradiction.

Comment: @angryavian could u tell me other ways of solving this question?

Comment: @graydad, so it's true that a basis generating an unique topology?

Comment: Should be true! I haven't rigorously proved it, but if you think about how the basis generates a topology, it doesn't seem possible that there could be more than one. You could probably prove this result too if you are unsure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sufficient, and here is why.

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_2)$ be topological spaces with the same basis $\mathcal{B}$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $\mathcal{T}_1 \neq \mathcal{T}_2$. Then $\mathcal{T}_1$ contains an element $V$ such that $V\notin \mathcal{T}_2$. Since $V \in \mathcal{T}_1$ there exists a collection of basic elements $\{B_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in \lambda} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ such that $$V = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \lambda} B_\alpha $$ And since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}_2$ then $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \lambda} B_\alpha$ is an element of $\mathcal{T}_2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Does the converse hold as well, i.e. if they are the same topologies, then they have the same base? Cheers!